# Slim Framework - Blank page when I deploy

Tags: php, apache, slim

I need some help to use Slim Framework. Indeed, I'm a beginner in PHP and I would like to migrate my API using Slim Framework in order to have a clean code. I successed to run Slim Hello Word app on my WAMP server locally, but when I deploy it on my OVH server shared, I have a blank page on route [root]/myproject/hello/test.

The question has already asked but the problem was not exactly the same.

For information I had a 500 internal error locally which was resolved when I've activated rewrite_module on my WAMP server.
I have a SSH access to OVH server but composer is not installed. It seems that mod_rewrite is enabled. WAMP and OVH server use PHP 5.5

This is my folder directory:

```
Project/
    src/
        public/
            .htaccess
            index.php
        vendor/
            autoload.php
            slim/
                slim/
                    Slim/
                        App.php
                        ...
        composer.json
        composer.lock
```

This is my **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

And my **index.php**

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

Any ideas to resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What's in error log?

Comment: Where I find it? It seems there is no error log files, just www/ directory and  .bash_history, .bash_logout, .bash_profiles

Answer (score 0):

try to use this .htaccess config

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also install monolog https://github.com/Flynsarmy/Slim-Monolog

Comment: Hum, on Firefox, in console log, I have a message which indicates I have a encoding issue so characters could be bad displayed. On Chrome, I have a 500 error,  not blank page, with message: Impossible to process mydomain.com for now (it's my trad). Is this help you?

Comment: This last error was a error caused by bad library import... So I have blank page again